# How can I get the exact match join for the below scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, join

How can i join the below tables

```
  TableA    TableB             TableC           TableD
  ID ID_C  ID  ID_A Value       ID            ID  ID_C Value
   1  1     1   1    a          1              1   1    a
            2   1    b                         2   1    b
```

in order to get the Result like

```
  Result
  ID ID_B Value  ID_C ID_D Value
  1   1     a      1     1  a
  1   2     b      1     2  b
```

and my result shouldn't contain 1 2 b 1 1 b and both value columns cannot  always have same values so it cannot be used in a condition.

To make it simplier,

```
   Resultant Table           TableA              TableB
   ID   Value                ID Value            ID  ID_A
    1   a                     1  a               1    1        
    1   b                     2  g               2    1
    2   a                     3  d               3    2
    3   c                                        4    3
```

Now i need to join the Resultant Table with TableA,TableB inorder to get some of the columns from TableA,TableB and ResultantTable.ID=TableA.ID and TableB.ID_A=TableA.ID since its a foreign key.

Doing the Join with TableB turns to duplicates. Since ID=1 occurs twice i get 4 records where ID=1, when there are only 2 records. It can be done with distinct or group by but i need other columns as well to be displayed.How do i do both in the process.

Comment: @kurozakura - "result shouldn't contain 1 2 b 1 1 b". Should it contain 1 2 b 1 1 a? If not, why not?

Comment: well, that is how the tables are , values a and b are like different states i need to retrieves both the states so mapping from table c -> table d and since theres no relation between table b and table D it ends up incorrect mappings because each record can have more than 1 states i.e a , b .

Comment: Ah, so TableB should be linked to TableD by Value.

Comment: @kurozakura, in the "simplified" scenario, you can't get that Resultant Table from TableA and TableB. Result values b and c are not present in TableA or TableB, while TableA values g and d are not present in the intended results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, B.Value, C.ID, D.ID, D.Value
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID_A
INNER JOIN TableC C ON A.ID_C = C.ID
INNER JOIN TableD D ON B.ID = D.ID AND C.ID = D.ID_C
```

Comment: B.ID and D.ID are not always equal.

Comment: A case illustrating that would be useful to include in your sample data and results.

Answer (score 0):

You tell us that the field "value" in TableB should not be different from the field "value" in TableD? Could we replace the B.ID = D.ID with B.Value = D.Value so solve your problem?

Are you sure, that is the way that is suppose to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID ID_B, B.Value Value_B, C.ID ID_C, D.ID ID_D, D.Value Value_D
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID_A
JOIN TableC C ON A.ID_C = C.ID
JOIN TableD D ON B.Value = D.Value AND C.ID = D.ID_C
```

Comment: i think the tables are not normalized properly

Comment: @kurozakura, in the "simplified" scenario, you can't get that Resultant Table from TableA and TableB. Result values b and c are not present in TableA or TableB, while TableA values g and d are not present in the intended results.